# Derivative of Summation

Tags: derivatives

How to handle summations with an additional factor in derivation?

Let's say I have a function

$$f(x)=\alpha*\sum_{i=0}g(x,i)$$

and I want to build the derivative $f'(x)$ of it. I know that the the derivative of a sum is equal to the sum of derivatives but what happens to $\alpha$?

Comment: $\alpha$'s a constant.  $f'(x) = \alpha*\sum_{i=0}g'(x,i)$.

Comment: $f(x) = a*\sum g(x,i) = \sum a*g(x,i)$ so $f'(x) = \sum (a*g(x,i))'   = \sum a g'(x,i) = a*\sum g'(x,i)$.

Comment: Let $K(x) = \sum g(x,i)$ then $(a* K(x))'=a*K'(x) = a*\sum g'(x,i)$. $a$ is a constant.  It's trivial....  Or chain rule!  $(aK(x))' = aK'(x) + a'K(x) = aK'(x) + 0*K(x) = aK'(x)$....

Comment: Thank you! If $\alpha=1/2$ and $g(x,i)^2$ would $\alpha$ be canceled?

Comment: Mmmm....no.  by chain rule $ (g (x,i))^2)' = 2(g (x,i))*g'(x,i) $  so $f'(x)= \sum g' (x,i)*g (x,i) $ so, yes the 2 qnd the 1/2 cancel out, but the higher power changes what the "rest" is.